# Constructing a UI to ask a list of questions

Tags: c++, c++14, constructor, user-interface, c++1z

This code fragment from 2009:

```
#include "../asklib.hxx"
std::vector<AskBase*> questions;
AskUI<std::vector<AskBase*> > ui(questions);
ui.add(new Ask<std::string>("Enter your name: ", 3, 25));
ui.add(new Ask<std::string>("Enter your city: ", 2, 25));
ui.add(new Ask<std::string>("Enter your state: ", 2, 2));
ui.add(new Ask<int>("Enter your age: ", 18, 150));
```

was modified to take advantage of C++14 features in the initialization of `questions`:

```
#include "../asklib.hxx"
// Define user interface.
std::vector<AskBase*> questions {
   new Ask<std::string>{"Enter your name: ",  3,  25},
   new Ask<std::string>{"Enter your city: ",  2,  25},
   new Ask<std::string>{"Enter your state: ", 2,   2},
   new Ask<int>        {"Enter your age: ",  18, 120}};
AskUI<std::vector<AskBase*>> ui {questions};

int main(){
  ui.run(); 
  if (ui.completed())
    for (auto ii: ui.items())
      std::cout << ii->id() << ii->l_answer_string() << std::endl;
}
```

As `questions` is not directly used in the routine later it seems like there should be a way to eliminate the variable by just passing the `std::vector<AskBase*>` directly the `AskUI` constructor. Are there suggestions for removing it or rational as to the necessity of it staying and any other comments? I'm looking for C++14 and/or C++1z answers.

The code review aspect is requested for the main file specifically for making the library easier to use. The contents of `asklib.hxx` and `asklib.cxx` follow thought other than regarding the improvements needed to support the user of the library it is not presented for the review request.

```
// asklib.hxx
#ifndef ASKLIB_HXX
#define ASKLIB_HXX
#include <vector>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#define gettext_noop(S) S
// ============================================================================
class AskBase {
// ============================================================================
private:
    class Locale{
    private:
        std::string     m_gtlocale; 
        std::string     m_gtdomain;
        std::string     m_gtdir;
    public:
        Locale(const char* a_gtlocale="", const char* a_gtdomain="asklib", const char* a_gtdir="./exp/po")
            :m_gtlocale(a_gtlocale), m_gtdomain(a_gtdomain), m_gtdir(a_gtdir){setLanguage("pl_PL.utf8");}
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void setLanguage(std::string a_language)
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            m_gtlocale = a_language;
            setlocale(LC_ALL, m_gtlocale.c_str());
            bindtextdomain(m_gtdomain.c_str(), m_gtdir.c_str());
            textdomain(m_gtdomain.c_str());
        }
    };
    struct Status {
        static auto const   c_ROOT          =-999;
        static auto const   c_PREVIOUS      =  -1;
        static auto const   c_NEXT          =   1;
        static auto const   c_EOF           = 999;
    };
    static int              c_instance;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_EOF;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_ROOT;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_PREVIOUS;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_HELP;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_VERSION;
    static const char*      c_e_REQ_LANGUAGE;
    static const char*      c_e_MSG_HELP;
    static auto const       c_MAX_TRIES     = 2;
private:
    decltype(AskBase::Status::c_ROOT)   ask_user();
    template<typename C>friend class AskUI;
    virtual bool        validate(std::string a_l_response) = 0;
    int                 m_instance_id;
protected:
    std::string         m_e_raw_prompt;
    std::string         m_l_answer_string;
public:
    Locale              c_locale;
                        AskBase(const char* a_e_prompt);
    void                changeLaguage(std::string a_language){c_locale.setLanguage(a_language);}
    std::string         l_prompt(){return gettext(m_e_raw_prompt.c_str());}
    std::string         l_answer_string(){return m_l_answer_string;}
    auto                id(){return m_instance_id;}
};
// ============================================================================
template<typename T>                            // ex: int, std::string
class Ask : public AskBase{
// ============================================================================
private:
    int     m_min;
    int     m_max;
    bool    validate(std::string a_l_response);
public:
            Ask(const char* a_e_raw_prompt, int a_min, int a_max)
                :AskBase{a_e_raw_prompt}, m_min{a_min}, m_max{a_max}{}
};
// ============================================================================
template<typename Container>
class AskUI {
// ============================================================================
private:
    int status = AskBase::Status::c_ROOT;
public:
    Container&  m_asks;
                AskUI(Container& a_asks, const char* a_gtlocale="")
                    :m_asks{a_asks}{}
    void        add(AskBase* a_ask){m_asks.push_back(a_ask);}
    bool        completed(){return AskBase::Status::c_NEXT==status;};
    Container&  items(){return m_asks;};
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    auto run()
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        for (typename Container::iterator ii=m_asks.begin();
                ii!=m_asks.end();
                ii=(AskBase::Status::c_ROOT==status)? m_asks.begin():
                    (AskBase::Status::c_PREVIOUS==status)?(m_asks.begin()==ii?m_asks.begin():ii-1):
                    (AskBase::Status::c_NEXT==status)?ii+1:
                    m_asks.end())
            status = (*ii)->ask_user();
        return;
    }
};
#endif

// asklib.cxx
#include "asklib.hxx"
// Input string the user enters to request program to exit.
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_EOF = gettext_noop("^Z");
// Input string the user enters to request control to go to the first prompt in the input tree.
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_ROOT = gettext_noop("^^");
// Input string the user enters to request control to go to the previous prompt.
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_PREVIOUS = gettext_noop("^");
// Input string the user enters to request version info to be displayed.
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_VERSION = gettext_noop("?v");
// Input string the user enters to request a new language. 
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_LANGUAGE = gettext_noop("^:");
// Input string the user enters to request help info to be displayed. 
const char* AskBase::c_e_REQ_HELP = gettext_noop("?");
// Help displays useful info for user, Version displays version of software, the remainder are navigation controls: Root
// directs control to the first prompt in the input tree, Previous directs control goes to previous input prompt, Exit
// terminates the program. 
const char* AskBase::c_e_MSG_HELP = gettext_noop(" %1$2s - Help\n %2$2s - Version\n %3$2s - Language\n %4$2s - Root\n %5$2s - Previous\n %6$2s - Exit\n");
int AskBase::c_instance = 0;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AskBase::AskBase(const char* a_e_prompt)
    :m_e_raw_prompt(a_e_prompt), m_instance_id(++c_instance)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if (1 == c_instance){
        c_locale.setLanguage("");
        }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
decltype(AskBase::Status::c_NEXT) AskBase::ask_user()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    for (auto tries_left = c_MAX_TRIES; tries_left > 0;)
    {
        std::cout << gettext(m_e_raw_prompt.c_str());
        std::string l_response;
        getline(std::cin, l_response);
        if (gettext(c_e_REQ_EOF) == l_response || std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad())
            return Status::c_EOF;
        else if (gettext(c_e_REQ_ROOT) == l_response)
            return Status::c_ROOT;
        else if (gettext(c_e_REQ_PREVIOUS) == l_response)
            return Status::c_PREVIOUS;
        else if (gettext(c_e_REQ_VERSION) == l_response)
            std::cout << SSVID_ICON << SSVID << std::endl;
        else if (gettext(c_e_REQ_LANGUAGE) == l_response){
            Ask<std::string> lang{"Enter new language: ", 2, 10};
            lang.ask_user();
            std::cout << "New language is: " << lang.l_answer_string() << std::endl;
            c_locale.setLanguage(lang.l_answer_string());
            }
        else if (gettext(c_e_REQ_HELP) == l_response)
            std::cout << boost::format(gettext(c_e_MSG_HELP))
                % gettext(c_e_REQ_HELP) % gettext(c_e_REQ_VERSION) % gettext(c_e_REQ_LANGUAGE) % gettext(c_e_REQ_ROOT) % gettext(c_e_REQ_PREVIOUS) % gettext(c_e_REQ_EOF);
        else if (validate(l_response)){
            m_l_answer_string = l_response;
            return Status::c_NEXT;
        }
        else
            --tries_left;
    }
    return Status::c_EOF;
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<>
bool Ask<std::string>::validate(std::string a_l_response)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if (a_l_response.length() < m_min)
        std::cout
            << boost::format(gettext("Invalid input. "))
            << boost::format(ngettext("Enter a string at least %d character long. ", "Enter a string at least %d characters long. ", m_min)) % m_min
            << std::endl;
    else if (a_l_response.length() > m_max)
        std::cout
            << boost::format(gettext("Invalid input. "))
            << boost::format(ngettext("Enter a string at most %d character long. ", "Enter a string at most %d characters long. ", m_max)) % m_max
            << std::endl;
    else
        return true;
    return false;
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<>
bool Ask<int>::validate(std::string a_l_response)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    int intAnswer;
    if (!(std::stringstream(a_l_response) >> intAnswer))
        std::cout
            << gettext("Invalid input. ")
            << gettext("Enter an integer.")
            << std::endl;
    else if (intAnswer < m_min)
        std::cout
            << boost::format(gettext("Invalid input. "))
            << boost::format(gettext("Enter at least %d. ")) % m_min
            << std::endl;
    else if (intAnswer > m_max)
        std::cout
            << boost::format(gettext("Invalid input. "))
            << boost::format(gettext("Enter at most %d. ")) % m_max
            << std::endl;
    else
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for something [like this](https://ideone.com/bl7u0s)?

Comment: Show some more of AskUI please. I would like to see how it's templated, method declarations, etc. I'll say for now, store your `AskBase*`s in `std::unique_ptr<AskBase>`. Raw pointers should never own anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to remind everybody of the importance of **minimal examples**.

```
#include <vector>

template<class Container> class AskUI {
    Container& m_ask;
public:
    AskUI(Container& a_ask) : m_ask(a_ask) {}
    int foo(int idx) { return m_ask.at(idx); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> questions = { 1, 2, 3 };
    AskUI<std::vector<int>> ui(questions);
    ui.foo(2);
}
```

Your question is, can we somehow remove the requirement that `questions` be a named variable in this code? Well, the short answer is "no"; `AskUI`'s constructor takes a Container by *non-const lvalue reference*, and so we have to have a non-const lvalue for it to refer to. What's more, in order to keep `ui.m_ask` from being a *dangling reference*, we need the referenced Container to live at least as long as `ui` itself. Otherwise, we could get away with something like

```
// Compiles, but yields undefined behavior (on OS X, throws std::out_of_range)
int main() {
    AskUI<const std::vector<int>> ui({ 1, 2, 3 });
    ui.foo(2);
}
```

The idiomatic C++11 way to write `AskUI` would be to have it make a *copy* of the passed-in Container, so that you could just pass in an anonymous (rvalue) Container and not have to worry about lifetimes. The `AskUI` itself would own and manage the lifetime of its Container.

```
template<class Container> class IdiomaticAskUI {
    Container m_ask;  // is now a value, not a reference!
public:
    template<class... Args>
    IdiomaticAskUI(Args&&... args) : m_ask{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
    int foo(int idx) { return m_ask.at(idx); }
};

int main() {
    IdiomaticAskUI<std::vector<int>> ui({ 1, 2, 3 });
    ui.foo(2);

    // And if you really NEED reference semantics, that's doable too:
    std::vector<int> questions = { 1, 2, 3 };
    IdiomaticAskUI<std::vector<int>&> ui2(questions);
    ui2.foo(2);
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to use minimal examples in your answer, but Code Review questions should not be reduced to minimal examples, else we wouldn't really be reviewing code anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, I had forgotten that this was on CodeReview. The OP's question (*As `questions` is not directly used in the routine later it seems like there should be a way to eliminate the variable by just passing the `std::vector<AskBase*>` directly [to] the `AskUI` constructor. Are there suggestions for removing it or rationale as to the necessity of it staying? I'm looking for C++14 and/or C++1z answers and any other comments.*) would have fit in better on StackOverflow, and I answered it (semi-accidentally) with a StackOverflow answer.